# Running the Camshift demo on an imported video

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the camshift algorithm to track the path of a colour invariant circle from a prerecorded video. I tried using the demo code found at https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/camshiftdemo.cpp but I'm trying to load a prerecorded video as my I keep getting an error asking me to insert a camera.

I modified the following line

```
VideoCapture cap;
Mat frame;
```

to

```
VideoCapture cap("C:/Users/samplefile.mov");
```

and then

```
cap.read(frame);
```

This method works for just importing a video but for the life of me, I can't get it to work with the demo. Am I doing it wrong?

P.S. Are there any other methods you could suggest to draw the bar path of a given circle in a video  within a region of interest? My main motivation for using the camshift algorithm is the fact that a user can simply just choose an area to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. There was an extra line

```
cap.open(camNum)
```

I missed this.